# anzograph - Cannot connect to the admin console

Tags: graph-databases, anzograph

I set up Anzograph DB Free Edition in Docker Desktop on my Mac, and (per the commands below) ran it. But I can’t connect to the admin console.

```
docker pull cambridgesemantics/anzograph

docker run cambridgesemantics/anzograph
```

When I use the inspect feature in Docker Desktop’s Dashboard, all of the ports for the running image are “not binded”. I would have expected to connect on port 5600 but that doesn’t work – not with localhost, not with 0.0.0.0, not with 127.0.0.1 …

Am I perhaps missing some pre-requisite? I allocated 8 GB of memory to Docker.

Answer (score 2):

From the information you documented, what you are seeing is true as you have not documented in your command the specific ports. 
What you entered was the following,

```
docker run cambridgesemantics/anzograph
```

What you should run to address this, which is documented on the download page for Anzograph, specifying the ports to install,

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443 --name=anzograph cambridgesemantics/anzograph:latest
```

Answer (score 2):

AnzoGraph frontend binds to port 8443 (https) and 8080 (http),
AnzoGraph DB binds to port 5600 (gRPC DB management) and 5700 (gRPC DB query) inside the docker container.

Docker Desktop for MAC is mapping these container internal ports to ports on localhost. If you do not tell docker how to map those ports, it uses a random strategy to allocate those ports on localhost. In specifying the mapping

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443  -p 5600:5600 -p 5700:5700 --name=anzograph cambridgesemantics/anzograph:2.1.1-latest
```

you tell docker what localhost ports to use ( -p { localhost port } : { port inside of container} )

Many users new to docker struggle, when they use for example Kitematic, or similar UIs, that make it simple to deploy a running docker container, however they face complexities understanding and determining these random ports.

So if you are new to docker, and you do not want to use kubernetes yet, please use the command line to specify the localhost ports - it ends up being easier.